# Fullcalendar Add Event

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Hey, I need to switch from jquery weekcalendar to fullcalendar and I am having troubles with understanding of adding new events. In weekcalendar its easy, I trigger the addEvent functions, open the dialog box and there I have my form and save everything ok with ajax. I also have a selectbox where are all times from the settings of first hour and end hour of the day. Is it possible to have something simmilar in fullcalendar? Weekcalendar has getTimeslotTimes() which deals with the time and it is easy to operate with it, what is the name of such function in fullcalendar?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm confused as to why someone would even need this. Surely your add event code is a server side issue (probably not explaining myself right here), and the full calendar will pick up the new event the next time the call to the db is made?

That's how i'm handling it in my app anyway.

Answer (score 0):

believe you are asking for something like this?
http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=162

(not implemented yet, just a feature request)